# How can I pass all parameters (one by one) in an object to a constructor in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, class, constructor, parameters

This is a hard question to do, but I'll try to explain.
I have the `Class` and the parameters of its contructor as an object. What I need to do is a function that returns an instance of this class, passing this parameters to the constructor.

This is the code:
Some random and unmodifiable class:

```
public Foo {
    public function Foo(a:int, b:String) {
        // constructor
    }
}
```

And some function (in some another class):

```
function bar(params:Object):* {  
    var baz:Foo = new Foo(params.a, params.b);
    return baz;
}
```

What I need to do is make this function generic, without pass `params` as parameter to `Foo` constructor because I can't modify it. Something like:

```
function bar2(clazz:Class, params:Object):* {
    var baz:* = new clazz(/*some magic way to transform params in comma separated parameters*/);
    return baz;
}
```

Anyone can help me?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is called parameterized factory. First I thought about `Function.apply`, but it doesn't *apply* to constructors (he-he). So, people are making factories like this:

```
function create(what:Class, args:Array):* {
    switch (args.length) {
        case 0: return new what();
        case 1: return new what(args[0]);
        case 2: return new what(args[0], args[1]);
        ...
        //PROFIT!
    }
    throw new Error("Need moar cases!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what about using ByteArrayto copy the object ?

```
function clone(source:Object):* {
    var copier:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    copier.writeObject(source);
    copier.position = 0;
    return(copier.readObject());
}

newObjectCopy = clone(originalObject);
```

[source](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?p=1897368)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option of not using a constructor, but adding an `initialise()` function to each class which can be constructed instead, you could use `Function.apply` - something like in the example below.

```
public class ThingCreator
{
    public static function createTheThing(c:Class, params:Array):Object
    {
        var the_thing:Object = new c();
        the_thing.initialise.apply(the_thing, params);
        return the_thing;
    }
}
```

As alxx pointed out above, Function.apply and AS3 reflection in this case does not seem to work with AS3's constructors.